# Importing a 3d model - do I have to use a custom vertex type for indexing?

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics

I'm importing a 3d model(using FBX SDK) with C++ and OpenGL.

I made a vertex type:

```
struct Vertex {
    Vec3 position;
    Vec2 texCoord;
    Vec3 normal;
    Vec3 binormal;
    Vec3 tangent;
    SkinInfo skin;
}
```

Currently, I'm assigning a `std::numeric_limits<float>::infinity()` to unused components when loads a model. And construct a mesh class with `std::vector<Vertex>`.

The ctor of a mesh class changes vertex list to interleaved array and calculates offset and stride, omitting unused components.

The problem is, when loading a model. In case of a simple object, there's only position, UV and normal info; what a waste of memory.

Maybe the best solution is a exporting fbx file to game-friendly format, but I don't have enough time.

I have to use indexed vertex array for performance(`glDrawElements`), but I cannot find a better solution without using a vertex type for deduplication and indexing. Any better idea?

Comment: Instead of `std::numeric_limits<float>::infinity()` you should use some NaN (not a number) value. either `…::quiet_NaN()` or `…::signaling:NaN()`.

Comment: @datenwolf Good point. I'll change it.

Comment: @dragon-kurve not really sure I got the question right, why not use separate arrays for each component? That's quite likely to have better cache utilisation too.

Comment: @keltar: That's not how it works. The GPU needs the *entire* vertex before it can begin processing data. With separate arrays, it has to make several memory reads before it can begin processing. With a single interleaved array, you only need one. It's not a huge performance deficit or anything, but interleaving is always preferred where possible.

Comment: @NicolBolas but you can freely disable some arrays where you don't need them (depth pre-pass, ....). Likely to give net positive, I think. And certainly better than NaN or INF gaps which will just destroy cache.

Comment: @keltar: But the solutions are not limited to "waste space in an interleaved array" and "use separate arrays". You can simply use interleaved arrays *properly*; nothing's stopping him from changing his vertex format to suit the data.

Comment: @keltar Whilst I'm using interleaved array, I disassemble a vertex to array of `float`s using the move semantic. If a first element of vertices has invalid component(INF or NaN or whatever) `glEnableVertexArrayAttrib()` also never called. So I don't think that would be a problem now. But I'll consider when I render several passes, btw.

Comment: @dragon-kurve I'm not really sure I understand your data layout from that description. If you write into vertex buffer in the same layout as specified in question, then you use much more video memory then necessary and thrash cache with unneeded data, disabling attribute will not change that. From what you say it seems you don't have any information regarding vertex format aside from special values in it - perhaps having `enum`, bool array or bitmask would be appropriate (and then either separate arrays or `union` accessor, depending on problems you need to solve).

Answer (score 1):

Most performance rendering applications have a (small) set of vertex formats they use. For your attributes, I see three possible vertex formats: unskinned/unbumpmapped, unskinned-with-bump-mapping, and skinned (with bump-mapping). There might be a possibility of a skinned-without-bump-mapping format too, but that's up to you and your data.

So you should have 3 separate formats (if you want to define them by C++ data structures, you can use 3 separate structs). You should render as much as you reasonably can without changing vertex formats though, so you should group models based on format. That is, if most of your terrain is unskinned, render all your terrain at once using the unskinned format.

In short, there is nothing *forcing* you to use a single vertex format. So if that's not appropriate for your needs, don't limit yourself to just that format.

Comment: Okay, I'll try various vertex formats and overload some functions.